# Creating a new document on google drive through the API

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to create a new document (either using a template or completely dynamic) using the Google Drive APIs? I am working with a client that requires generation of word documents. I tired looking up but I couldn't find sufficient documentation on how to "create and format" documents using the APIs.

For example, can I include the client's company logo on the top of the doc programmatically? I'd like whatever I am doing for this client to be generic (i.e including logo at the top etc) to be dynamic, so I can re-purpose this for other clients as well.

I also am having difficulty finding documentation on any kind of formatting we could do on the documents (bold, italic, new paragraph) etc

Answer (score 5):

The Google Drive API **only** deals with whole file operations. It has no understanding of the content of the files, including formatting.

You have two options:-

1. Use Apps Script (ie. not the Drive API) which has document manipulation features. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/
2. Create your templates in HTML (or Word, OpenOffice), then upload them to a new file, setting the option to 'convert to google docs'

Comment: Thanks. Option 2 seems very attractive if I can simply use html/css and upload the styled document to the drive. Is 'convert to google docs' a manual setting on a folder/file or can it be set programmatically?

Comment: convert=true is an argument to the insert API call. It is the programmatic equivalent of specifying convert when uploading a file using the Drive web UI. Before committing to any coding for option 2, you should test the fidelity of the upload using the web UI. I suspect (haven't tested it much) that only basic HTML formatting is imported. You will have greater fidelity using Word or Openoffice.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create new documents as well as make a copy of already existing documents (templates)
Some time ago I've created simple example how to work with templates:

On your [Google drive](https://drive.google.com) create folder Templates

Inside this folder create formated document with images, texts etc... Replace dynamic values with {A},{B},{C} representing spreadsheet column names in this document

Than create spreadsheet and fill some data in it. Inside this spreadsheet navigate to Tools->Script gallery and search for *fast template generator* -> Install it

Close document and re-open it. Script will automatically execute *onOpen* function which will add Template generator to spreadsheet menu. Now just choose row from which you would like to populate values in template and launch *Template generator*-> *Generate from template*.

A new document with filled values will be generated from chosen template.

You can find source code and customize it in according  your need in *Tools*->*Script editor* in this spreadsheet, so result should be in PDF or sent via email etc...

Comment: This seems like a manual process. Will the document be generated automatically from the spreadsheet if I upload a new spreadsheet? I can't have clients login to the drive and do all this stuff. They would want a link to a document that has their logo and some custom stuff about their users (depending on which user the document content can change).

Comment: You can modify the script according your needs and add event triggers such as: On document open, edit, change, on form submit, or time driven...

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Seems this approach does not work, as Google Drive API only allows copying files across current user's Drive.

I found for me suitable approach was to create a document in my own Google Drive. Style it accordingly, add base text etc. and give it read-only permission to everyone. Then from the Google Drive API use copy file functionality and copy it into the current users Drive.