# Java programatically create and save a google doc

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-apps

Google has `Docs`, `Sheets`, `Slides` and `Forms`. I would like to use `Java` to create a `Google word Docs`. **Is this doable?** I've been looking for an hour now.

I need an `idiot's` guide to how to install the library and setup my first mini test. I'm the idiot :) I downloaded the [library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/download) but i can't seem to figure out how to use it in a regular Java Project. This is NOT Android or Gradle project, nor is it a web based project. It is setup as a god old fashioned java project!

I tried installing the Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.4 but i have no idea what i'm doing. I can't find a decent tutorial on how to get started.

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction :)

**EDIT**

Hi, sorry for the confusion. I do **not** want to work in `Java Script`. The current project i have is `Java` which generates various types of reports. I want to add Google Doc as an export format.

**EDIT 2**

Example, i downloaded `Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.4` but the video tutorial is out of date and i cannot figure out how to use it to add the `.jar` to my project. I can't even find all the library files online.

Comment: Make sure to tell us if it's Java or JavaScript. You have JavaScript related tags but you say Java.

Comment: Dan added the JS tags from what i can see. OP was asking about java. He even said `regular java` project.

Comment: @Zig Mandel Hi, thank you for the reply. I am looking for `Java` and not `JavaScript`. I don't know how the JavaScript tag got in there, i didn't put it :(

Comment: To make a valid question, please include the error(s) you are seeing, or what exactly isnt working. Yes its possible to convert a google doc into a ".doc" file.

Comment: @Zig Mandel i didn't post errors because i don't even know if what i'm doing is right. I don't need you to do my work for me, i would just like to ask you to point in the right direction. If you have a guide on how to setup and get started. That's all :) Also i am not trying to convert a google doc into anything. I want to create a google doc with java.

Comment: your question says a "Word" doc, now it says a Google doc. very different. Also, stackoverflow is not the right place to ask for tutorials. You need to try something, and show us exactly where you got stuck so we can help.

Comment: @Zig Mandel I meant google word doc, not microsoft word doc. I've tried a few things but i don't know if i've even gone about it the right way or if i'm using the right tool. Google doesn't explain clearly what's for cloud, android, pc, etc. That why my question is simple. What do i use to create a google word document or google spreadsheet with a java application on pc. You don't even have to provide me with a guide. Just which of their api's am i supposed to use. It can't be `android` or `gradle` based, and has to be run as a java application. It's the simplest of questions :)

Comment: alright, then its NOT a "word" document, is a Google document. This is already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21519165/2213940

Answer (score 0):

`Google Apps Script`  is a web based script which is very akin to Java **Script**. With GAS, you can of course create Google Docs, which Google handles as blobs.

You can do something like this:

```
// Open a document by ID.
var doc = DocumentApp.openById('DOCUMENT_ID_GOES_HERE');

// Create and open a document.
doc = DocumentApp.create('Document Name');
```

You can also programatically edit documents. Please refer to : [Document Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/)

We can help you better, if you are more precise.

**EDIT:**

I apologize for being mistaken. May be [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/java) could be of some help, but it is no way an "idiot's" guide. Sorry once again. :(

Comment: From my understanding, he wants to create a java project and work in java. Dan edited his post and removed the tags lol. Well he's asking for an idiot's guide on how to setup the environment and the necessary libraries and the smallest possible java example. I was actually looking for something similar myself since i'm having issues with their tutorials.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. I do not want to work in Java Script. The current project i have is Java which generates various types of reports. I want to add Google Doc as an export format.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood somehow. Edited with the link: [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/java). Don't know if it is of much help. :(

Comment: @Br.Sayan I'm new to this so i'm not sure but as far as i know `Java Projects` and `Gradle Projects`  while both are written in Java are different from each other and incompatible. I'm looking for a guide on how to do this with a regular `Java Project`. I saw that guide as well. Google did a very poor job at explaining all their apir's :( Thank you for trying though! =D